# Is there partial tail call optimization for recursive functions?

Tags: c++, recursion, optimization, tail-recursion

How can I do tail call optimization on g++ on a function that is not completely tail recursive?

For example:

```
void foo(Node *n) {
    if (n == nullptr) return;

    foo(n->left);
    cout << n->datum;
    foo(n->right);
}
```

This is foo(n->left) is not tail recursive, but foo(n->right) is. Is there a way to optimize this?

Comment: if you are paranoid about this you can always transform your recursive function into an iterative one (just to be clear, I am not recommending to do it, just pointing it out you can)

Comment: g++ [inlined the first 9 calls](https://godbolt.org/g/TEJvLv) on -O3 to avoid doing any recursion if it can.  On -O2 it was a bit less silly and just transformed the second call into a jump.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: ask your compiler, very nicely.

The C++ specification allows the compiler to implement any optimization as long as the observable results remain the same.

In the shown code, the partial tail optimization will obviously produce identical observable results. Whether it actually happens, that depends entirely on your compiler. The C++ specification does not require the compiler to perform tail optimization here, but it doesn't prohibit it, either. This is entirely up to your compiler, and it's fairly likely that a modern C++ compiler will do this, at a sufficiently aggressive optimization level.